# Split Foreach Output with Unordered List

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce

I am attempting to add a brands menu into an eCommerce website (PHP MVC structure). I have successfully managed to obtain output but the problem is that this is output as a single list.

My coding knowledge is limited so I am unsure how to split this into multiple lists.

I have read other answers here that are similar but they are different enough that I remain unsure how to proceed.

This is the code in the controller file:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');

$this->data['manufacturers'] = array();

$results = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $this->data['manufacturers'][] = array(
        'name'            => $result['name'],
        'href'            => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id'])
    );
}
```

This is the code in the template file:

```
<div class="brand">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Could anyone be kind enough to advise which code should be added to split the HTML output into 3 unordered lists instead of 1?

**Edit for further clarification.**

The manufacturers are output as a single unordered list, as expected.

Like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>Manufacturer 1</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 2</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 3</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 4</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 5</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 6</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 7</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 8</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 9</li>
</ul>
```

I am looking to output:

```
<ul>
  <li>Manufacturer 1</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 2</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Manufacturer 4</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 5</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Manufacturer 7</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 8</li>
  <li>Manufacturer 9</li>
</ul>
```

In summary, the logic should count the number manufacturers and divide this by a predetermined figure (in this case, 3) and then output three unordered lists with an equal number of children.

So as per the example. There were 9 manufacturers which resulted in 3 unordered lists with 3 children in each.

Comment: It's not clear what you want in each of the lists. If you could give some sample data and expected results that would be helpful.

Comment: you can leave the '$this->' out, you only need $data['x']. same thing in the foreach loop

Comment: Thank you for any help you can provide Nick. I have edited the original question to further clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_chunk` for this: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

What you're doing here is, you are making chunks of the array, meaning you are seperating the array into x pieces.

```
 <?php 
 foreach (array_chunk($manufacturers, 3, true) as $manufacturer) { ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($manufacturer as $value) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $value['name']; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

do print_r($manufacturers) and see what you are getting

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. It should be a comment.